# Strike tag from html is not working with attributeText objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to place a strikethrough text in a label with the help of html tag
like the below text..
Some <strike>html string</strike>
The label is defined as below.

```
self.lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[self.lbl setFont:REGULAR(13.0)];
self.lbl.text = @"ABCD";
self.lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

self.lblMarquee = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.lblMarquee.marqueeType = MLContinuous;
self.lblMarquee.rate = 30.0f;
self.lblMarquee.trailingBuffer = kTableViewMediumPadding;
self.lblMarquee.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[self.lblMarquee setFont:REGULAR(14.0)];
self.lblMarquee.text = @"ABCD";
self.lblMarquee.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.lblMarquee.numberOfLines = 0;
```

So I tried the below code to get a strike

```
NSString * htmlString = @"Some <strike>html string </strike>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
cell.cellView.lbl.attributedText = attrStr;
```

the above code displays a plain text i.e., 
Some html string.. not the strikedout text..
I have used `NSUTF8StringEncoding` in place of `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` but that didnt helped either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some experiments I found that it is a problem with `UILabel` that it doesn't support `<strike>` tag I had to replace the `UILabel` with `UITextView`...Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only strikethrough text, alternatively, you can do this way:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your sample text here."];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@1
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

<YOUR LABEL>.attributedText = attributeString;
```

Comment: actually the text will be dynamically set so i dont know about which word would be striked out n which not